# Auto-Renewable Subscriptions

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, auto-renewing

i am working with auto Renewable subscription inApp Purchase, after verify the apple purchase receipt i get following response. Now what is difference between `latest_receipt_info` and `receipt`. what is difference between `orignal_purchase_date` and `purchase_date`

---

```
{
    "latest_receipt" = "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";
    "latest_receipt_info" =     
    {
        bid = "com.candidMarket.com";
        bvrs = "1.0";
        "expires_date" = 1355655285000;
        "expires_date_formatted" = "2012-12-16 10:54:45 Etc/GMT";
        "expires_date_formatted_pst" = "2012-12-16 02:54:45 America/Los_Angeles";
        "item_id" = 588124128;
        "original_purchase_date" = "2012-12-16 07:23:11 Etc/GMT";
        "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1355642591000;
        "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2012-12-15 23:23:11 America/Los_Angeles";
        "original_transaction_id" = 1000000060542119;
        "product_id" = candidMarket101;
        "purchase_date" = "2012-12-16 10:49:45 Etc/GMT";
        "purchase_date_ms" = 1355654985000;
        "purchase_date_pst" = "2012-12-16 02:49:45 America/Los_Angeles";
        quantity = 1;
        "transaction_id" = 1000000060544594;
        "unique_identifier" = 2cc1d763f86c47ffe24b1ac9f351c3ae126c8144;
        "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000026481135;
    };
    receipt =     
    {
        bid = "com.candidMarket.com";
        bvrs = "1.0";
        "expires_date" = 1355643190000;
        "expires_date_formatted" = "2012-12-16 07:33:10 Etc/GMT";
        "expires_date_formatted_pst" = "2012-12-15 23:33:10 America/Los_Angeles";
        "item_id" = 588124128;
        "original_purchase_date" = "2012-12-16 07:23:11 Etc/GMT";
        "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1355642591000;
        "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2012-12-15 23:23:11 America/Los_Angeles";
        "original_transaction_id" = 1000000060542119;
        "product_id" = candidMarket101;
        "purchase_date" = "2012-12-16 07:28:10 Etc/GMT";
        "purchase_date_ms" = 1355642890000;
        "purchase_date_pst" = "2012-12-15 23:28:10 America/Los_Angeles";
        quantity = 1;
        "transaction_id" = 1000000060542139;
        "unique_identifier" = 2cc1d763f86c47ffe24b1ac9f351c3ae126c8144;
        "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000026481035;
    };
    status = 0;
}
```

Comment: hi,In my app currently i am using the autorenewing. I implemented and the transcation is working fine, but i need to get the receipt depends upon my requirements, can you send the sample to reterive the recepit. I didnt get such kind of result. can you suggest me?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the receipt field contains the first `receipt` info, and the `latest_receipt_info` contains the receipt from the latest transaction. I'm waiting for the renewal to confirm that.

Assuming this, the first transaction would have those 2 fields identical.

They supposed to be different on renewal

The `original_purchase_date` is the date which the subscription has started (the user successfully subscribed) the `purchase_date` is the date where the last invoice took place (renewal for instance). both will be almost identical if its the first transaction (situation when the user just subscribed for the first time). as seen in the receipt data